# CircuitLab schematic editor not working?

Tags: bug

Is anyone else unable to insert schematics into answers/questions at the moment? I can load the schematic editor but when I try to insert it, it just hangs, and either it closes without having inserted, or I have to close it myself and I lose the diagram.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem just a few minutes ago -- each time I pressed "save and insert", then closed the editor, only to find nothing had been inserted. After 3 drafts starting over from nothing, the circuit got simpler and simpler...

Anyway it appears to be working now. The thing I was editing is here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/166993/35022

Comment: It's just started working for me again too

Comment: And yeh my circuit ended up just having a ground terminal :-p Something very Zen about that. Good thing too, as I was nearly throwing the damn thing out the window